# Is it bad to edit a Rails database directly?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app which uses a mysql database. The app is being used to display records from log files (think Apache log files) which are generated every hour.

I already have a script that adds these records to a separate mysql database. Is it bad if I modify my script to convert the records and store them in the mysql database that Rails already uses, rather than having Rails parse the logs and add them itself?

Comment: I don't see any problem with doing that... have you tried it? If so did it cause any kind of problems?

Comment: Been doing it for a while now and haven't had any problems so far. But I'm not an expert on database security

Comment: Yeah I cannot think of any reason that this should cause problems. As long as you aren't trying to manually write over `schema.rb` and are just using your database API to manually insert/update records that shouldn't matter to rails. You can have a rails app with a database you create/manage yourself and that you don't let rails touch at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's completely fine. Database supports already multiple connections, and usually you have multiple rails processes accessing the database at the same time, so it's perfectly fine, your script that loads data in your database is just another connection.

One thing you must be careful of, if you have validation logic in Rails and not in your database (this is the standard case), remember that the stuff you add with the script won't be validated. That's all. Basically, **database consistency is your responsability** once you bypass rails.